# Graph node search - Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, [a])’ with actual type ‘[(a, [a])]’

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I need to write a function checkNode that accepts a graph in form of:

`[(1,[2,3]), (2, [3,4])]`

as an argument where the first integer in a Tuple is a Node and the list shows all the other Nodes the initial Node is connected to.

checkNode has a second parameter, an Integer.

`checkNode [(1,[2,3]), (2, [3,4])] 2` outputs True, because 2 is a node in the graph, whereas

`checkNode [(1,[2,3]), (2, [3,4])] 7` outputs False.

Here's what I have so far:

```
checkNode :: (Eq a, Num a) => [(a, [a])] -> a -> Bool
checkNode [] _ = False
checkNode [(x,_):d] n = if (n == x) then True else checkNode d n
```

and here's the error:

```
test2.hs:53:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, [a])’
                  with actual type ‘[(a, [a])]’
    • In the pattern: (x, _) : d
      In the pattern: [(x, _) : d]
      In an equation for ‘checkNode’:
          checkNode [(x, _) : d] n = if (n == x) then True else checkNode d n
    • Relevant bindings include
        checkNode :: [(a, [a])] -> a -> Bool (bound at test2.hs:52:1)    
| 53 | checkNode [(x,_):d] n = if (n == x) then True else checkNode d n    |            
                  ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Is `4` a member of grap `[(1,[2,3]), (2, [3,4])]`? It has an edge to `4`, but not from `4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to alter the way the function reads the graph input:

```
checkNode :: (Eq a, Num a) => [(a, [a])] -> a -> Bool
checkNode [] _ = False
checkNode ((x,_):d) n = if (n == x) then True else checkNode d n
```

Namely, enclose the graph in the round brackets.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to only check if there is an edge leaving that item (so the query is in the first item of one of the 2-tuples), you can check with:

```
checkNode :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f (a, b) -> a -> Bool
checkNode graph q = any ((q ==) . fst) graph
```

this will check if any item in the `Foldable` (that can be a list) is a 2-tuple with `q` as first item.

This will not check if there is an incoming edge for a node, so `4` is not a node of the graph `[(2, [4])]` for example.

Comment: The question asks not about how to solve the task, but instead about why the compiler is signaling a type error. The common (according to recent StackOverflow questions) mistake of pattern matching a list as `[x:xs]` instead of `x:xs` is what should be pointed out here.